# Batch import large amounts of data

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the REST API for batch import with Neo4j 2.0 M06

When I import a few thousand items, it works fine, but if I try to import a few hundred thousand nodes with relations, I get a server error.

Is there a way to enable paging on the batch import so I don't have to put too much data in the request to the server? Or is there another solution?

I would like to import everything at once, since I want to refer to earlier items late in the import process. For example when I'm at item 200 000, I might want to refer to {15} so I want to avoid running multiple import commands so I don't loose the references.

Comment: What server error are you getting? Can you use indices so you can do lookups in the db for those later references, or dig them out of previous responses from the server?

Comment: there's an excellect blog post out there: http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/

Comment: I get http code 500. I will try the things in the blog post and see if it helps.

Comment: I want to import bulk data in neo4j using REST API. If you have any solution for "the server error" which you were facing, please share with us, will be helpful.